# Declaring a property in interface with a setter accessible to inheritors but not instantiators

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I want to force my inheritors to contain a property *Propy* so I designed the following.

```
public interface Enforcer
{
  string Propy { get; set; }
}
```

Between the interface and the actual classes, I need to use an abstract base class to enforce constructor signature. Then, the implementer class and the inheritor class look like so.

```
public class Implementer : Enforcer
{
  public string Propy { get; set; }

  public Implementer(string propy) { Propy = propy; }
}
```

Now, if I instantiate that class, I have random access to the property, which I want to restrict. I can't declare the setter as private or protected because accessibility modifiers may not be used on accessors in an interface. I can't make the property all private because I need to access it (read-only, of course) in the runner class.

```
public class Inheritor : Implementer
{
  public Inheritor(string propy) : base(propy) { }
}

public class Instantiator
{
  public void Main()
  {
    Inheritor thing = new Inheritor("blopp");
    string propy = thing.Propy;
    thing.Propy = "bzz";
  }
}
```

I want the last statement to be invalid but not the second last. I googled my butt off but I'm guessing it's a bit unusual scenario (which can be handled sloppily by simply allowing the property to be public and hoping that the users respect the boundaries. I want purely academically see ow to do it the right way.

Comment: Whatever you decide on your interface should be public, so in your interface remove the `set;` of your property. In your abstract class you can make the setter `protected`: `... { get; protected set; }`, this will allow the property to be writable only within implementations of your class. If you don't want that, you can either make the setter `private`. Add the last option, of your using C# or above, you can remove the `set;` altogether and make your property read-only, only accessible in your abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

In an interface, you cannot restrict access to properties, so I don't think you can force classes that implement that interface to restrict that access.

Alternatively you could use an abstract class, in which you *can* restrict access, but a not-so-benevolent implementer could still easily override the abstract class restricted-access property.

```
interface IMyClass
{
    string MyProperty { get; } // this does nothing against implementing a setter!
}

abstract class MyAbstracClass : IMyClass
{
    string MyProperty { get; protected set; } // otherwise we cannot set it from inheritors
}

class MyClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public new string MyProperty { get; set; } // nothing stops this!
    public MyClass (string prop) => MyProperty = prop;
}
```

The abstract class option *does* mean a developer cannot "accidentally" expose the property. Even if you *do* manage to keep it hidden, any developer who really, really wants to get access to a private property can simply use reflection, anyway. That also doesn't happen accidentally, though, and should always raise red flags at a code review!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Implementer : Enforcer
{
    private string _propy;
    public string Propy
    { 
        get
        {
            return _propy;
        }
        set
        {
            // do nothing. so readonly.
        }
    }
    public Implementer(string propy) { _propy = propy; }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't suffice the conditions. I have to rely that whoever implements *Enforcer* kindly doesn't tamper with *set* method. I'm looking for a non-sloppy by-the-book approach where they **can't** tamper with it.

Comment: Even if this _would_ be acceptable, `public string Propy  {  get; }` does the same.

Comment: @oerkelens You're right on both comments, so I hope you see my issue from a higher skill set perspective. Care to throw in a suggestion of your own? Or am I to start expecting that the precise requirement of mine isn't achievable?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Implementer : Enforcer
{
    private readonly string _propy;

    public string Propy
    {
        get => _propy;
        set => throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    public Implementer(string propy) { _propy = propy; }
}
```

throw an exception when it is set or you could just change your interface to only get and do a private set in your implementation

Comment: If this would satisfy the OP's question, it can be done _much_ easier:`public string Propy  {  get; }`.

Comment: The user @oerkelens is right. I don't want to **rely** on the benevolence of the implementer. I wish to assume that they're a jackass with malicious intentions and create a technical obstacle to prevent them for jackassing in the logic.

Comment: You can change your interface to only have get so that no one can set it, as what I said on my followup..